# paypal posting back transaction id and identity token fail 4020

Tags: post, paypal, eclipse-pdt

I am integrating paypal into my site at the final stage of my own shopping cart.
I am just practising in the sandbox at the moment. So I have a form in my shopping cart page which sends the price of each item to paypal at this address https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

This works fine because it comes back to my return url with the transaction id after the user enters their payment details on paypal. Now I am stuck at the part where I send back the transaction id with my identity token as it returns fail 4020.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="monk@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Electro">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Dub">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="2">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

</form>
```

so in my return url i have this:

```
<?php 

$transID = $_GET['tx'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<form target="paypal" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch">
                <input type="hidden" name="tx" id="tx" value="<?php echo $transID; ?>"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="at" id="at" value="myIdentityNumber"> 
                <input type="submit" value="PDT"> 
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In my return url 'MyIdentityNumber' is replaced with the identity token in my sandbox business account. I have read a lot of information about it and I can't find the right info. Thanks a mil for any advice.
Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had actually mis-copied my identity token leaving out one character. haha. Silly mistake but as least its working now. Thanks